# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '3-1' to data type int

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
    USE Zoo

    CREATE TABLE dbo.TypeDetail
    (
        ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        AnimalID nvarchar(6) NOT NULL,
        TypeID int NOT NULL
    )

    INSERT INTO dbo.TypeDetail (AnimalID, TypeID)
    VALUES
    (1, 5),
    (1, 8),
    (2, 5),
    (2, 8),
    (3, 5),
    (3, 8),
    ('3-1', 5),
    ('3-1', 8),
    (4, 6),
    (5, 6),
    (6, 6),
    (6, 3),
    ('6-1', 6),
    ('6-1', 15),
    ('6-2', 6),
    ('6-2', 3)
```

I'm trying to use this to insert the value '3-1' into this table, however I always get an error saying that it's trying to convert that value into an int.  I need that as a varchar, so anyone have an answer?

Comment: of course the real question is "Why is AnimalID a nvarchar(6)?" It shouldn't be...

Answer (score 2):

You have mixed data types for the first column values in the table value constructor of the `INSERT` statement. Some are integers, e.g. `6`, and some are strings, e.g. `'6-1'`. According to the rules for [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql) they are all converted to `int`.

If you change the values so that the value for the first column are all strings, e.g. `'6'`, there won't be a problem.

The following code snippet demonstrates the feature:

```
select Val, SQL_Variant_Property( Val, 'BaseType' ) as BaseType
  from ( values ( '1' ), ( 2 ) ) as PH( Val );
```

Try changing the type of the values, e.g. `'2'` or add `3.14`, and see what happens.

An explanation is in the documentation for [table value constructor data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql#data-types).

Comment: In other words, you need to enclose the values in the `nvarchar` column in quotes. You should write `'1'` instead of `1`.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov Yes, all of the values need to be strings in quotes. (If you throw in another value and data type in the example code, e.g. `3.14`, all of the values change to `numeric`.) (Or `cast` or `convert` to a string data type, but simply adding the quotes is easier.)

Answer (score 0):

Curiosity overwhelms me as to what int (numeric without decimal values) value you believe a dash would be translated to.  3-1=2?  31?  Do you wish to do the math before inserting the value, or will you require the minus sign/dash?

If you require the minus sign, then your column has to be a character data type, which means you've lost the ability to perform mathematical expressions on it.

If you don't require the minus sign (as Mitch states above) and the column is intended to hold integer values then there should be some kind of data entry filter to enforce all values entered are integers, and the columns should be defined as an int.  Otherwise you're just setting yourself up for future errors.

Comment: The column is declared `AnimalID nvarchar(6) NOT NULL` and the value is `'3-1'`, so the question is: Where is the conversion to `INT`?